# Is it possible to scrape data from Sofascore on Live Games?

Tags: web-scraping

I am new to web scrape so apologise in advance if this is simple to do.

What I would like is scrape live on-going games.

My purpose is to look for Yellow & Red Cards and goalscorers once they are added to sofascore I would like it to print the information back to me.

Here is my test code so far but I think I have done it incorrectly, is there any way around this?

I would really appreciate the help regarding this.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.sofascore.com/ajax-chelsea-fc-women/tKBskpwb#id:12049907"

# Fetch the page content
response = requests.get(url)
if response.status_code == 200:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

    # Find all div elements with specified attributes
    player_divs = soup.find_all('div', {'elevation': '2', 'class': 'sc-fqkvVR grUnmB', 'fill': 'var(--secondary-default)'})
    
    if player_divs:
        for player_div in player_divs:
            # Extract player name from the parent div
            player_name = player_div.find_parent('div', class_='sc-EHOje gzAAoj').find('span', class_='name').text.strip()
            print("Player Name:", player_name)
    else:
        print("No player names found matching the specified criteria.")
else:
    print("Failed to fetch the page. Status code:", response.status_code)
```

I did a print but was unable to sort my issue

Comment: Missing crucial information: what is the error you get? I get a 403 error.

Comment: Moreover, the URL contains `ajax` (`Javascript`) and the site is behind Cloudfare. You have 2 new issues. This is not a task for a beginner, or you need to have good search skills.